# VBA - invalid qualifier when getting array length

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a function that puts the param into an array, then returns a random index value of the array. My code gets a `compile error: invalid qualifier` at `arr.Length`. So far I have:

```
Function myFunction(List As Range)
    Dim arr()
    Dim indx

    arr = List
    indx = (Int(Rnd()) * arr.Length)   'error here

    myFunction = indx
End Function
```

Not sure if I am using the array right, or returning the value right - Please help

**REVISION 1**

Replaced .length with ubound and lbound - now I am getting a `#VALUE` error in the cell when it should be returning the array's index value.

```
Function myFunction(List as Range)

    Dim arr()
    Dim indx as Integer

    arr = List
    indx = Int(Rnd() * (UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1)) 'indx

    myFunction = arr(indx)
End Function
```

Comment: VBA Arrays don't have a `Length` property: use `UBound()` and `LBound()`

Comment: okay made the edit, which worked (thank you). I am stuck on yet another problem, the cell won't return the index value (see revision)

Comment: Change `Dim indx` to `Dim indx As Integer`

Comment: @Daniel this did not seem to work

Comment: When you assign the Value of a Range to an array, you get a 2-D array with dimensions (1 to numberOfRows, 1 to numberOfCols).  You'll need to adjust your code so you're indexing correctly into that array.  It's unclear what the shape of the input range is, so it's hard to make a specific suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign the Value of a Range to an array, you get a 2-D array with dimensions `(1 to numberOfRows, 1 to numberOfCols)`, so the solution is to change `arr(indx)` to

```
Function myFunction(List as Range)

    Dim arr()
    Dim indx as Integer

    arr = List
    indx = Int(Rnd() * (UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1)) 'indx

    myFunction = arr(indx,1)
End Function
```